# ¿Cómo se dice "Gold digger" en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, inglés

En inglés, la frase "gold digger" tiene connotaciones de una persona que utiliza su relación para aprovecharse de otra persona inocente para conseguir dinero y otro lujos.

¿Cómo se dice "gold digger" en español con las mismas connotaciones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe varias palabras para indicar una persona que utiliza su relación para aprovecharse de otra persona para conseguir dinero y otros lujos;

- **Cazafortunas** (Es la que más se asemeja al sentido Inglés).

**Gold Digger** -Someone, usually a woman, who tries to attract a rich person, usually a man, in order to get presents or money.

- *Dictionary Cambridge*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/gold-digger

- *Dictionary Collins*

**Gold-Digger**, A gold-digger is a person who has a relationship with someone who is rich in order to get money or expensive things from them.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles/gold-digger

"**Gold digger**" o **Cazafortunas**, es una persona que usa sus atracciones sexuales para acumular regalos y riqueza o avanzar en su posición social.

---

Comment: Creo que ninguna de estas palabras tiene nada que ver directamente con el sentido de la pregunta. Ya puestos puedes incluir bombero, presidente o patinador.

Comment: Eres muy simpático.  El Cazafortunas (Gold Digger). Miniserie de TV  del año 2019, DRAMA, INTRIGA, THRILLER Título original: Gold Digger. Título en España: El Cazafortunas, con Julia Ormond y Ben Barnes. Definición de Gold-digger 
... Otra definición de "gold digger" es una mujer que usa sus atracciones sexuales para acumular regalos y riqueza o avanzar en su posición social.

Comment: Las traducciones de los títulos de series y películas en España no son un buen aval a tener en cuenta para absolutamente ninguna reivindicación. Cuando la madre de Marty McFly confunde su nombre por el bordado que lleva en los calzoncillos, versión original: Calvin Klein, versión española: Levi Strauss. Se cargaron media película. En todo caso, si tus respuestas se basan en traducciones hechas por medios masivos españoles, quizás sea conveniente añadir la aclaración. Poner un listado de probabilidades a una pregunta concreta solo genera confusión e incertidumbre.

Comment: «Gold Digger» —en español: «cazafortunas»— es una canción interpretada por el rapero estadounidense Kanye West con la colaboración musical del cantante rhythm and blues Jamie Foxx.

Comment: Gold Digger -Someone, usually a woman, who tries to attract a rich person, usually a man, in order to get presents or money. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/gold-digger

Comment: Ok, que hacemos con "alcahueta", "sirena", "fulano", "sacamaridos" entonces? No tienen absolutamente nada que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: cazafortunas, si. Los outros, no.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta de @Diego está bien tirada, aunque su sentido literal esté limitado al tema "amoroso". https://dle.rae.es/cazafortunas

Comment: @Danielillo Creo que encaja mejor "cazafortunas" que "aprovechado". Tampoco hace falta atacar a las opiniones de los demás.

Comment: Thanks to @JoaquinMarcher for the edit suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

### Aprovechado

> 3. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que saca beneficio de las circunstancias que se le presentan favorables, normalmente sin escrúpulos.

<sub>*Fuente [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/aprovechado)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre **vividor**:

> adj. Que vive a expensas de los demás, buscando por malos medios lo que necesita o le conviene. U. t. c. s.

Otra palabra que se acerca a esta idea es **cazadotes**, aunque el Diccionario de la lengua sólo hace referencia al hombre respecto de la mujer:

**cazadotes**

> m. Hombre que trata de casarse con una mujer rica.